# How can I get the ABSOLUTE line reference when getting an error warning in DataGrip?

Tags: sql, console, datagrip

I usually run many different SQL queries on the same DataGrip console so I might have more than a thousand lines of code.

When there is something wrong with one of the queries, I get a warning message in DataGrip which explains the error and gives me a reference about where in the query the error is located. The annoying problem is, that reference is relative to where the query started so it's way less useful than what it could be. If the reference was absolute I could much faster understand where the error is located in my console because DataGrip UI has a continous count of lines across the whole console, it does not start from 0 for every query.

Here is an example: In the same console, I write 3 SQL queries, which amount for 263 lines of code. I run the last query and get an error. DataGrip warns me about the error and says the error is in line 13. Now I need to go check in which line the query started (line 180), sum up the 13 lines and get the absolute reference where the error is located in the console (line 193). I want DataGrip to tell me the error is on line 193 straight away so I don't have to make the annoying calculation every time I need to find the error. This should be super easy because DataGrip knows in which line the query started every time you run one, and it also knows the absolute reference of every coded line in the console.

I have not been able to find any option to accomplish my purpose.

Comment: What database do you use?
Related feature request for Oracle: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-11635

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, DataGrip does not support the functionality to navigate directly from an error message to the console.

To stay up to date follow the issue [DBE-11635](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-11635)